# Preserving file info while creating tar in PHP

Tags: php, tar, phar

In PHP, I created tar file using Phar object but it does not save the file info like the modified time, permissions etc.

Is there any way to save such info in the tar file created?

I tried buildFromDirectory(), addFile(), nothing works.

Comment: It doesn't look like there's any way to control how `Phar` constructs the archive.

Answer (score 0):

The phar file format does actually contain "meta data" for files - see the description at http://php.net/manual/en/phar.fileformat.manifestfile.php

By default, no meta data are stored on the files. You can check that with the `phar` tool provided in the PHP release zips:

```
$ phar meta-get -f phorkie-0.5.0.phar -e www/www-security.php
No Metadata
```

But since you asked how you can add them: with `meta-set`:

```
$ php -dphar.readonly=0 `which phar` meta-set -f phorkie-0.5.0.phar\
      -e www/www-security.php -m 's:8:"hi there";'
$ phar meta-get -f phorkie-0.5.0.phar -e www/www-security.php
s:8:"hi there";
```

---

Programmatically, you can use [PharFileInfo::setMetadata()](http://php.net/manual/en/pharfileinfo.setmetadata.php).